# react-native-fs, expo-file-system and rn-fetch-blob, will not overwrite a file on android simulator and real device

Tags: react-native, expo, filesystems, react-native-fs, expo-file-system

I am trying to overwrite an image with a new image on Ios works perefctly, but on android it only creates the file the first time and then you cannot ovewrite it. I tried react-native-fs, expo-file-system and rn-fetch-blob, all give me the same result. I am using android 10 on real device and android 12 simulator.

react-native-fs

```
  const path = "file://" + RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/sign.png";

   RNFS.writeFile(
        path,
        signature.replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""),
        "base64"
      )
        .then(() => {
          dispatch(createSignature(path));
        })
        .catch(console.error);
```

expo

```
 const path = FileSystem.cacheDirectory + "sign.png";
      FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
        path,
        signature.replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""),
        { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 }
      )
        .then(() => FileSystem.getInfoAsync(path))
        .then(() => dispatch(createSignature(path)))
        .catch(console.error);
      setSign(signature);
```

rn-fetch-blob

```
      RNFetchBlob.fs
        .writeFile(
          `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir}/sign.png`,
          signature.replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""),
          "base64"
        )
        .then(() => {
          dispatch(createSignature(path));
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: Either it should file write permission issues other services/processes are already using that file . Try to delete old file then write new file with same path

Comment: I already tried deleting the old file like this  RNFS.unlink(path).then(() => { RNFS.writeFile(path, content)); }); , also tried to change stream = reactContext.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri, append ? "wa" : "rwt"); in the RNFSManager.java. Nothing worked. https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/700

Comment: I am also facing this issue, everything is working great on IOS but android it will not overwrite anything. Have you found a solution to this? @Radjapa

Comment: I think the problem is Android is cashing them so I haven't tested but if you add Date.now() to the file path FileSystem.cacheDirectory + "sign${Date.now()}.png", and then when you want to update it, just delete the old one and replace it with the updated one  @hugger

Comment: Thanks man you lead me into the right direction, I got it working! @Radjapa

Comment: @Radjapa I posted a question a couple days ago regarding this, go ahead and answer it there and I'll give you a check